# Configuring ActiveResource to support OAuth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, activeresource, basecamp, 37-signals

I need to be able configure ActiveResource to connect with OAuth2 or basic authentication on a connection by connection basis.  I have found a couple ways to configure ActiveResource with OAuth2, but they don't seem that elegant and don't lend themselves to a dynamic type configuration.  Any help out there?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Koala? We use it for dynamic Oauth authentication.

Comment: Please explain specificially what you mean by "dynamic type configuration".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to do this by having my ActiveResource classes inherit from an intermediate class:

```
  class Resource < ActiveResource::Base
  end

  class MyClass < Resource
  end
```

This allows you to dynamically set the authentication (as well as site, format, etc) for all classes that inherit from the intermediate Resource class:

if the user has OAuth2 configured:

```
   Resource.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + my_oauth2_token
```

or if the user is just using basic authentication:

```
   Resource.user = my_user_name
   Resource.password = my_password
```

Hope this helps someone!