# How to use a Google API as my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to use the Google Books API as the model for one of the controllers in my Rails app. Basically -I would still like this to act as a scaffold (though I won't be posting to / modifying it)

But I would still like to have a Book object, and be able to do a `Book.find([google_book_id])`.

What is the best way to go about setting something like this up? Should I generate a scaffold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Google Books API seems to be a typical REST service, I would start by looking at [ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource). It's a way of implementing ActiveRecord-ish models where the data is stored in an external service instead of your database. If you set up a `Book` model using ActiveResource, you would indeed be able to call `Book.find(google_book_id)` and have it return a Book object with the properties returned from the API.

Since I've never used ActiveResource myself I can't offer you much advice on the details, but it looks like you would need a way to either [use OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656315/configuring-activeresource-to-support-oauth2) or [add an API key parameter to each request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918419/add-api-key-to-every-request-in-activeresource).